# Add a COUNT(*) with 3 Tables

Tags: mysql

I´m trying to create a query for 3 tables to use with a PHP While, to show all students and the count number of lessons they already had.

This is what I already have. It shows all students and the Language he is learning (secciones table)

```
"
SELECT t1.*
     , t2.nombre as nombre_seccion 
  FROM estudiantes t1 
  JOIN secciones t2 
    ON t1.id_seccion = t2.id 
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC
";
```

I need to add a COUNT of the quantity of the lessons (clases.id_clase) by student (clases.id_alumno)

**TABLES**

```
**::: clases :::**
    
id_clase | fecha_clase | contenido | deberes | comentarios | id_alumno


**:: estudiantes ::**

id | nombre | dead | promedio | imagen | id_seccion | fecha | plataforma


**:: secciones ::**

id | nombre
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide a minimal reproducible example for best results on answers, and try to use English as much as possible: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Something like this subquery might work:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.nombre as nombre_seccion,
(
    SELECT COUNT(st3.id_clase) FROM clases st3
    INNER JOIN estudiantes st1 ON st1.id = st3.id_alumno
    WHERE t1.id = st1.id GROUP BY st3.id_alumno
) AS num_classes
FROM estudiantes t1 
INNER JOIN secciones t2 
ON t1.id_seccion = t2.id ORDER BY t2.id DESC
```

Comment: But there's no incentive is there

Comment: Thanks Damjan , i will revise the link you posted , sorry . 
I tested the query into MYSQL and I it works, but the only thing seems not working is the alias, the new alias column is called : ( SELECT COUNT(st3.id_clase) AS 'num_classes' FROM clases st3 INNER JOIN estudiantes st1 ON st1.id = st3.id_alumno WHERE t1.id = st1.id GROUP BY st3.id_alumno ) .

Comment: Updated the answer, I think that should fix it